# ASP.NET Core Web API - Create Custom Requests and Responses

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm completely new to .NET and C# programming. I'm working on a project that requires me to develop a .NET base web application.

I have been able to do most parts of the project but I'm having issues with the ASP.NET Core Web API.

I want to make HTTP Get request from the front end but I do not know how to remove the `WeatherForecast` sample and write my own requests and response.

Any help regarding how to create the basic template for the HTTP requests would be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You can use this Microsoft documents [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I want to make HTTP Get request from the front end`Web api doesn't contain front end.If you want to send requests in web api,you can try to use HttpClient,here is a sample with get request:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
 HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("{url}");
```

For more details,you can refer to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0).